# Python - Return problem with random.randint()

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, attributes

```
import random
    
print("""
___  ___          _           ___  ____           _ 
|  \/  |         | |          |  \/  (_)         | |
| .  . | __ _ ___| |_ ___ _ __| .  . |_ _ __   __| |
| |\/| |/ _` / __| __/ _ \ '__| |\/| | | '_ \ / _` |
| |  | | (_| \__ \ ||  __/ |  | |  | | | | | | (_| |
\_|  |_/\__,_|___/\__\___|_|  \_|  |_/_|_| |_|\__,_|

                                                    """)

meno = input("""
    Ahoj nový hráč. 
    Pre pokračovanie zadaj svoje meno: """)

print("""
    Ahoj {}
    Pravidlá sú následovné. ja si myslím číslo a ty budeš hádať.
    Ak chceš ukončiť hru, napíš 'KONIEC'.
    Na konci hry uvidíš svoje skóre.""".format(meno))

print("\nMyslím si číslo")

random = random.randint(1,11)
guess = -1
good = 0
bad = 0
alltry = 0
while True:
    guess = input("Tvoj typ: ").strip().lower()
    alltry += 1
    if guess == "koniec":
        alltry -= 1
        print("\n+{:=^30}+".format("KONIEC"))
        print("|{:^15}|{:^14}|".format("Správne", good))
        print("|{:^15}|{:^14}|".format("Nesprávne", bad))
        print("|{:^15}|{:^14}|".format("Spolu", alltry))
        print("+{:=^30}+".format(""))
        print("\nĎakujem za hru {}\n".format(meno))
        break
    if guess == "":
        print("NEZADAL SI CISLO!")
    elif int(guess) == random:
        good += 1
        print("Máš to!!!")
        random = random.randint(1,11)
        guess = -1
    elif int(guess) < 1 or int(guess) > 10:
        print("ZADÁVAJ ČÍSLA IBA Z INTERVALU OD 1 PO 10!")
    elif guess != random:
        print("NESPRÁVNE!\nHádaj znovu.")
        guess = -1
        bad += 1
```

Hi I have problem with this code. It is game MasterMind. If guess number, program return problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "mastermind.py", line 47, in <module> random = random.randint(1,11). AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: This is pretty simply: The line `random = random.randint(1,11)` turns `random` into a variable integer as opposed to a reference to the module called random. Rename your variable to `random_int = random.randint(1,11)` or something.

Comment: @niko, it's usually *always* simple to those answering the question, not necessarily so for those *asking* it :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo You are right  (that being said it was not meant with a negative connotation in any form or shape)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
random = random.randint(1,11)
```

This statement rebinds the `random` name, which currently refers to the imported module (it was set when you did `import random`), to an *integer* returned from `randint()`. The next time you execute this statement, `random` will no longer be the module, it will be an integer.

*That's* why it's complaining about trying to access a non-existent attribute of an `int` object.

The following transcript shows what's happening:

```
>>> import random
>>> type(random)
<class 'module'>

>>> random = random.randint(1,7)
>>> type(random)
<class 'int'>

>>> random = random.randint(1,7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

To fix, simply use a *different* name for the random value, such as `randNum`, so that `random` continues to be bound to the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `random` as a variable name since that is a module you are using, simply change the variable name and it should fix the issue.

Here I changed it to `random_int` instead and it works just fine.

```
import random

print("""
___  ___          _           ___  ____           _
|  \/  |         | |          |  \/  (_)         | |
| .  . | __ _ ___| |_ ___ _ __| .  . |_ _ __   __| |
| |\/| |/ _` / __| __/ _ \ '__| |\/| | | '_ \ / _` |
| |  | | (_| \__ \ ||  __/ |  | |  | | | | | | (_| |
\_|  |_/\__,_|___/\__\___|_|  \_|  |_/_|_| |_|\__,_|

                                                    """)

meno = input("""
    Ahoj nový hráč.
    Pre pokračovanie zadaj svoje meno: """)

print("""
    Ahoj {}
    Pravidlá sú následovné. ja si myslím číslo a ty budeš hádať.
    Ak chceš ukončiť hru, napíš 'KONIEC'.
    Na konci hry uvidíš svoje skóre.""".format(meno))

print("\nMyslím si číslo")

random_int = random.randint(1,11)
guess = -1
good = 0
bad = 0
alltry = 0
while True:
    guess = input("Tvoj typ: ").strip().lower()
    alltry += 1
    if guess == "koniec":
        alltry -= 1
        print("\n+{:=^30}+".format("KONIEC"))
        print("|{:^15}|{:^14}|".format("Správne", good))
        print("|{:^15}|{:^14}|".format("Nesprávne", bad))
        print("|{:^15}|{:^14}|".format("Spolu", alltry))
        print("+{:=^30}+".format(""))
        print("\nĎakujem za hru {}\n".format(meno))
        break
    if guess == "":
        print("NEZADAL SI CISLO!")
    elif int(guess) == random_int:
        good += 1
        print("Máš to!!!")
        random_int = random.randint(1,11)
        guess = -1
    elif int(guess) < 1 or int(guess) > 10:
        print("ZADÁVAJ ČÍSLA IBA Z INTERVALU OD 1 PO 10!")
    elif guess != random_int:
        print("NESPRÁVNE!\nHádaj znovu.")
        guess = -1
        bad += 1
```

Comment: @RadoslavDugas Mark the question as solved by pressing the check mark next to the correct answer. So that people know that the issule has been solved.